# Use private domain from old instance for SAP in new Instance?

Tags: marketing-cloud, enterprise, sfmc-business-unit, sender-authentication-package

I am currently working on moving a brand to a new instance and their own BU. They have the domain they want to use set as a private domain in the old instance. I am wondering if i could use it for the SAP set up in their own new BU.

Comment: Yes, but you will anyway need to go through the usual SAP setup process. Best open a support ticket because this is not something that you will be able to do on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just wanted to make sure.